# creating file from returned byte array via WCF Rest Service

Tags: wcf, file, rest, arrays

I am working on creating a WCF rest service. I have a function that will return a byte array of a file created by the service. I was wondering how I can create this file, from the byte array on the client side. This is in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write all received bytes to the file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("filename.bin", receivedBytesArray);
```

Save stream to file:

```
Stream receivedStream = // do some staff to receive stream

using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite("myfilepath.bin"))
{
    receivedStream.CopyTo(stream);
}
```

Comment: That does seem to make sense. I guess my next question, and maybe I should ask this in a different post. How to I actually receive the byte array.

Right now I am using a WebRequest/WebResponse and the byte array is actually being received as a stream.

Comment: Simply copy the received stream to the file stream and on the second sample.

Comment: So this creates the file? A question that is brought up is, what If I want the file to be named the same as the file being transferred?

Comment: You need to transfer the file name too. By `Stream` or `byte[]` impossible to identify the file name.

Comment: @gberg927 The Content-Disposition header and its filename parameter should be used to provide the name of the file. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html